# How to move head of bone to 0,0,0 and have the other selected bones and mesh move equally with it?

Tags: mesh, transform-orientation

My apologies if I have worded this poorly. I would like to move everything I have selected in this image, and I would like to move it all by the bone joint that I have the cursor set to. Is there a way to move this all with setting the bone joint to 0,0,0 and it all shift at once?

I have a feeling there is a button or option I am missing somewhere and I just don't know what it is called. Thank you

[image]

This is when attempting Fjoersteller's recommendation in Edit Mode, only the bone moves but it's positioning looks correct, I just need the mesh to move with it now. (When having both selected in Object Mode and 'Selected to Cursor' nothing happens)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Shift + C to move the 3d cursor to 0,0,0. Shift + S > Selection to Cursor. I think that should work (from what I can see in your image).

Comment: Thank you much, I think I almost have it. I think I might be selecting them in the wrong order perhaps, or in the wrong way? In edit mode the bone moved to the right place but I couldn't figure out how to select the mesh as well for it to move with it. If I select the bone and the mesh in Object Mode in either order and attempt to move it by Selection to Cursor, then nothing seems to move.

Comment: I don't think you want to move your mesh or armature in edit mode; then you will move them away from their Origin, which can cause all kinds of weird behavior. Go to 3D Viewport > Object > Set Origin and pick one (Origin to Geometry for instance), or use it in combination with selecting stuff, Shift + S, and the 3D Cursor to get it in the best location for you. Origins can only be moved in Object Mode. Make sure the Object Origins are the right place, and move your rigged body as a whole in Object Mode. I think that might be your issue.

Comment: This looks to have solved my issue, thank you very much. I was able to set the cursor to the head of the bone in Edit Mode, then in Object Mode I moved the origin to cursor. I then moved the cursor to world origin and finally selected all and moved selection to cursor. I am unable to mark it as the answer but if you repost it as the answer I will mark it as such.

Comment: Good idea; no need for others to look at an already answered question. In any case, happy to help : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you want to move your mesh or armature in edit mode; then you will move them away from their Origin, which can cause all kinds of weird behavior. Go to 3D Viewport > Object > Set Origin and pick one (Origin to Geometry for instance), or use it in combination with selecting stuff, Shift + S, and the 3D Cursor to get it in the best location for you. Origins can only be moved in Object Mode. Make sure the Object Origins are the right place, and move your rigged body as a whole in Object Mode.